# Custom IServer implementation does not work with IISIntegration

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

I've a sample asp.net core app with custom Implementation of IServer interface as following:

```
namespace AspNetCoreAppWithOwinHttpListenerServer
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebHost host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseHttpListener()
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }

    public class OwinHttpListenerServer : IServer
    {
        private IDisposable _HttpListenerServer;

        public IFeatureCollection Features { get; } = new FeatureCollection();

        public OwinHttpListenerServer()
        {
            Features.Set<IServerAddressesFeature>(new ServerAddressesFeature());
        }

        public void Start<TContext>(IHttpApplication<TContext> application)
        {
            Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> appFunc = async env =>
            {
                FeatureCollection features = new FeatureCollection(new OwinFeatureCollection(env));

                TContext context = application.CreateContext(features);

                try
                {
                    await application.ProcessRequestAsync(context);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    application.DisposeContext(context, ex);
                    throw;
                }

                application.DisposeContext(context, null);

            };

            appFunc = OwinWebSocketAcceptAdapter.AdaptWebSockets(appFunc);

            Dictionary<string, object> props = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            props["host.Addresses"] = Features
                .Get<IServerAddressesFeature>()
                .Addresses
                .Select(add => new Uri(add))
                .Select(add => new Address(add.Scheme, add.Host, add.Port.ToString(), add.LocalPath).Dictionary)
                .ToList();

            OwinServerFactory.Initialize(props);

            _HttpListenerServer = OwinServerFactory.Create(appFunc, props);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _HttpListenerServer?.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public static class OwinHttpListenerWebHostBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IWebHostBuilder UseHttpListener(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IServer, OwinHttpListenerServer>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine without IIS, but running on IIS or IISExpress results in "did not listen on the given port" by VSIISExeLauncher.exe.

How can I make my custom server compatible with IIS?
Thanks in advance.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/ymoradi/AspNetCoreAppWithOwinHttpListenerServer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AspNetCoreModule (IIS) is incompatible with Http.Sys based servers. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/23

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But I think there is something wrong with my Implementation too. I we're not able to use "Nowin" too. That server is implemented entirely in .NET and has no dependency to .NET / Windows Http Listener nor http.sys

Comment: I wasn't able to delete my question, I'll open new one with Nowin implementation, And I've to fix my last comment, Nowin has no dependency to http.sys, .NET HttpListener itself is based on http.sys. This is a thing that I wasn't aware of that. (: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OwinHttpListener is based on .NET HttpListenerClass and that class is implemented by help of http.sys.
http.sys is a kernel mode code, and for now, there is no support for that in asp.net core iis module.